# javascript ajax how to prevent duplicated submissions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, javascript-objects, ajaxform

Issue description:

I have a web application,once I fast click the "Add Parts" button multiple times in a very short time,there will be multiple duplicated records.

Here is the html:

```
<form id="addform">
  <div class="loading d-none">
    <button>
      <span role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      Processing...
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="loaded">
    <button>Add Parts</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
function sLoading(element) {
    $(element).find('div.loading').removeClass('d-none');
    $(element).find('div.loaded').addClass('d-none');
    $(element).find('div.error').addClass('d-none');
};

function sLoaded(element) {
    $(element).find('div.loading').addClass('d-none'); 
    $(element).find('div.loaded').removeClass('d-none');
    $(element).find('div.error').addClass('d-none');

};
```

Here is where the ajax has been applied:

```
function addFrom(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var changeNeeded = false;
    var form = $('#addform');
    if (changeNeeded) {
        sLoading(form);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/sheet/' + ID + '/parts',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(event) {
                sLoaded(form);
                window.location.reload();
        });
    } 
};

$('#addFrom').submit(addFrom);
```

Comment: disable the submit button and enable it only after getting the response from the server. Meanwhile also put throttle in the server so that a user can't submit under x amounts of seconds (depending upon your need) even if he attempts.

Comment: @itachi thank you very much for your reply ,can you give me more detail answer about  how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had a situation like this.

> Solution is to disable the submit button after form submission. So it can prevent multiple form submission and you have to specify the type of button is submit

I made a scenario like this, you does not want any loading or loaded functions and i used set timeout instead of your api

```js
function sLoading(element) {
    $(element).find('div.loading').removeClass('d-none');
    $(element).find('div.loaded').addClass('d-none');
    $(element).find('div.error').addClass('d-none');
};

function sLoaded(element) {
    $(element).find('div.loading').addClass('d-none'); 
    $(element).find('div.loaded').removeClass('d-none');
    $(element).find('div.error').addClass('d-none');

};
function addForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //var changeNeeded = false;
    var button = $(this).find("#submit");
    button.prop('disabled',true).text('processing...');
    
    //sLoading(form);
    setTimeout(()=>{
      button.prop('disabled',false).text('Add Parts')
    },1000)
   /* if (changeNeeded) {
        sLoading(form);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/sheet/' + ID + '/parts',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(event) {
                //sLoaded(form);
                button.prop('disabled',false)
                window.location.reload();
        });
    } */
};

$('#addform').submit(addForm);
```

```css
.d-none{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="addform">
  <!--<div class="loading d-none">
    <button>
      <span role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      Processing...
    </button>
  </div> -->
  <div class="loaded">
    <button id='submit' type='submit'>Add Parts</button>
  </div>
</form>
```